# C language assignment to expression with array type

Tags: c, file

I guys I have this struct

```
typedef struct objeto livro;
struct objeto
{
    char titulo[100], autor[100];
    int cota;
};
```

And this code:

```
int main()
{
FILE *f;
int tam=5, i=0;
livro c[5];
char a={"a"};

f == fopen("bib.dat", "wb");

if(f == NULL)
{
    printf("erro ao abrir ficheiro");
}

for(i=0; i<tam; i++)
{
    (*c).titulo=a;
    (*c).autor=a;
    (*c).cota=i;
    fwrite(c, sizeof(c), 1,f);
}

return 0;
}
```

but it says error:assignment to expression with array type on:

```
(*c).titulo=a;
(*c).autor=a;
```

I have tried everything I've seen here in the posts my i cant make it work

Comment: `a` is a single char. `titulo` is an array of chars. Therefore the error says you can’t assign them, which is correct. You probably want to use some variant of `strncpy()`

Comment: I think you should learn C language. That's the way the language goes: you cannot assign to an array, full stop. You can assign to pointers, or copy arrays with `memcopy`, but never try to assign to an array. BTW, `char a={"a"};` is a *horror*: `a` is a single character while "a" is a string literal that is the const array `{'a', '\0'}`. Please use `char a = 'a';` for a single char or `char a[] = "a"` for a C string.

Comment: The `char a={"a"};` is probably giving you a compiler warning, if not an error. If you want `a` to be an initialized array of characters containing a string, declare it as `char a[] = "a";`. And as pointed out by Sami Kuhmonen, you cannot use an array as the left side of an assignment.

Comment: Did you want `c[i]` instead of `(*c)` (which is the same as `c[0]`)?

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, `char a = {"a"};` is wrong as `a` is a single char variable but double quotation `"a"` means thats a string literal. To overcome this error first declare `a` is a char array like

```
char a[10] = "a";
```

And then use `strcpy()` or `strncpy()`, as `(*c).titulo=a` won't work because `a` is now declared as array & assigning one char array to another char array directly  like `(*c).titulo=a` will try to change base address of `titulo` which is not possible.

Replace below statement

```
(*c).titulo=a;
(*c).autor=a;
```

with

```
strcpy((*c).titulo,a);
strcpy((*c).autor,a);
```

Secondly, the statement

```
f == fopen("bib.dat", "wb");
```

is wrong, probably you want to use `=` instead of `==`

```
f = fopen("bib.dat", "wb");
```

Comment: `{} means array of characters`..you may want to rephrase. say, `{1,2,3}`

Comment: Thanks. I modified @SouravGhosh

Answer (score 0):

Use the library function strncpy()for strings.